# Wifi Network-manager icon in green color Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

Ubuntu 20.04, does any of you knows why the icon tray is displayed as green?

When this happen also the wifi stops working.

I found this on the web [but they trolled the poor guy.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/mgyx44/why_is_my_wifi_indicator_green/)

It only happens when I connect to certain wifi network, the others work well.

My chipset Wireless-AC 9462

[My screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpERO.png)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1915175). No way to solve it yet, it seems.